# How to Counting numbers of the Slick Slider thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slick.js

in a website that i developed , i using the "Slick Slider" and i want to count the numbers of the thumbnails, in the Jquery / js file i write the thumbnails will show as 5 , with centerMode:true,
i want (with your help, of course) to write a function that count the number of the thumbnails -
When the number is 5 **OR LESS**  than the option of centerMode will be false (so if this 5 thumbnails or 2 thumbnails when this is on false the thumbnails will be centered bottom the big picture),
When this 5 thumbnails an ABOVE this working fine.

Thank you For Advanced...

This is the code what i have (but when the thumbnails is 5 or less they are not centered)

```
   /** Project Slider **/
  $('.single-project-slider-wrraper').slick({
      rtl: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      fade: true,
      asNavFor: '.single-project-nav-wrraper'
  });
  $('.single-project-nav-wrraper').slick({
      rtl: true,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      asNavFor: '.single-project-slider-wrraper',
      dots: false,
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      arrows: true,
      focusOnSelect: true
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if no one answer to me so i give the answer - the solution was that i need to switch between the js files of slick slider. i loaded the minified js ( it turns out that  somthing wrong there..i don't know what ) and i needed to load the full/normal js file - slick.js , when i loaded the slick.js file the slider behave as i want (as i ask in the post above exactly ).

maybe it is strange but this is the solution :-)